# FFMPEG to Youtube Live

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have an audio stream, im using ffmpeg to stream it to youtube live with an image as background with following command,

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i x.jpg -i  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:5305/stream -c:a aac -s 1280x720 -ab 128k -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxx`

But im getting the following message on youtube,

`YouTube is not receiving enough video to maintain smooth streaming. As such, viewers will experience buffering`

this cause buffering in the output stream.

Any one know how to fix it ?

Helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `-g 50` to periodically insert keyframes.

Answer (score 13):

After a lot of trial and error the solution below works pretty much perfectly. To make sure it runs 24/7 wrap it inside a service of some description.

This is with an up to date version of FFMPEG to include -stream_loop -1.
The background is an mp4 file.
`http://localhost:3888` = an audio stream.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i $MYPATH/background/$background \
-i http://localhost:3888 -filter:a "volume=$volume" \
-r 24 -g 48 -pix_fmt yuv420p -x264-params keyint=48:min-keyint=48:scenecut=-1 \
-s $size -b:v $bitrate -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -acodec aac \
-vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -bufsize 960k -crf 28 -threads 2 \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$key
```

Config File:

```
# Config File
background=out.mp4
size=1280x720
bitrate=1500k
key=----KEY----
volume=0.5
```

EDIT -- Old Solution below

So i have a solution.

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i test1.jpg -i https://xxxxxxx:8443/live.ogg -c:a aac -s 2560x1440 -ab 128k -maxrate 2048k -bufsize 2048k -framerate 30 -g 60 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The important parts are the

> -re

at the start which deals with a buffering issue.
Then the

> -framerate 2

between the "-loop 1" and the image. This works and i get a good clean high quality stream that does not buffer.

Hoped this helped!

**Edit 1**

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i test1.jpg -i https://xxxxxxxxxxx:8443/live.ogg -c:a aac -s 2560x1440 -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -maxrate 2048k -bufsize 2048k -framerate 30 -g 2 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Ok So this updated version should fix almost all problems with the stream.

> -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p

Changed to H.264 Codex Fixed that problem

> -g 2

This fixes the final buffering issue.

Comment: what version of ffmpeg are you on?

Comment: @moeiscool should work on the current verson, i have not tested!

Comment: my problem is that i tried 3.3(a static build) and 3.2.4 (ppa).. this is on ubuntu 17 btw... It refuses to work. When i start FFMPEG it will give the green light on youtube for about 20 seconds then go grey and nothing shows up.. eventually it will say offline... leaving me with a video uploaded to my channel possibly blasting all my users with a whole lot of nothing :P

Comment: I wonder if there is away to hide YouTube key from the command line. Running `ffmpeg` like this can make your key visible to other system users, they can do `ps -Af ` and see your key (if they have enough privileges on the system) in the process list.
A possible solution could be reading the target YouTube url from a file, is it possible?

Comment: @AlexParamonov Is this possible via: `ffmpeg ... "$YTUBE/$(cat keyfile)"`?

Answer (score 3):

The last code is excellent, but I am still getting error message regarding "video resolution" on youtube Live with the latest command. I fixed it by replacing:

```
yuv420p with yuvj420p
```

I probed jpg with ffprobe and it returned the above yuv420p